# Turn x numpy arrays with dimensions [n, m] into a single array with dimensions [x, n, m] in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, image-processing, scikit-image

I am doing some image processing in Python. I have a set of grey scale images (512 x 512) saved in a stacked .tif file with 201 images. When I open this file with `skimage.io.imread`, it generates a 3D array with dimensions `[201, 512, 512]`, allowing me to easily iterate over each greyscale image - which is what I desire.

After performing some operations on these images, I have a list of ten 2D arrays, which I want to put back into the same dimension format that `skimage.io.imread` produced - ie. `[10, 512, 512]`.

Using numpy.dstack produces an array with dimension `[512, 512, 10]`. And numpy.concatenate does not do the job either.

How can I turn this list of 2D arrays into a 3D array with the dimensions specified above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is considering you have an array of shape `[512, 512, 10]` and move the last axis to the first:

```py
import numpy as np
imgs = np.random.random((512, 512, 10))

imgs = np.moveaxis(imgs, -1, 0)
print(imgs.shape)
# (10, 512, 512)
```

The other ways is to use `np.vstack()` like:

```py
import numpy as np

# List of 10 images of size (512 x 512) each
imgs = [np.random.random((512, 512)) for _ in range(10)]

output = np.vstack([x[None, ...] for x in imgs])
print(output.shape)
# (10, 512, 512)
```

Answer (score 0):

The most general solution is to use plain `np.stack` and specify which axis you want to add to the array.

Taking the notation from [@amrind's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68183928/2988730):

```
result = np.stack(imgs, axis=0)
```

This is roughly equivalent to just doing

```
result = np.array(imgs)
```